# Oracle - NCLOB getting issue - inserted value too large for column

Tags: oracle10g

I am working on Oracle10g, And I am currently facing one issue regarding NCLOB column.

Application uses Silverlight, WCF, NHibernate and oracle10g database.

Application firing one select query, in that query, it contains XML data for NCLOB column and it is giving me the following error:

"inserted value too large for column".

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Mahesh